# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los modos de abrir ficheros en Python con "open()"?

Tags: python, archivo

Con frecuencia me ocurre que quiero abrir un fichero en Python para añadir contenido, o bien crearlo desde cero, y me confundo un poco con el uso de *a*, *r*, *a+*, *r+* y demás. Sé que uno añade, otro crea desde cero, otro actualiza...

Lo mismo a la hora de leerlo con *r* y *r+*.

¿Cuál es la diferencia entre los modos de abrir un fichero?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1466000/1983854

Comment: En conexión con lo mismo, el otro error frecuente es usar `close` dentro de un `with`. ¿Tal vez una pregunta/respuesta sobre el uso de `with`?

Comment: @CandidMoe cierto, genera mucha duda. Algo [como esta de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9282967/1983854) iría muy bien, ¡te animo a añadirla!

Comment: @CandidMoe veo que [la añadiste](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/397718/83), qué bien.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Existen todas estas opciones:

- `r`
  abre un fichero para su lectura. Cursor al principio.
- `r+`
  abre un fichero para su lectura y escritura. Cursor al principio.
- `w`
  trunca o crea el fichero para su escritura. Cursor al principio.
- `w+`
  trunca o crea el fichero para su escritura y lectura. Cursor al principio.
- `a`
  abre un fichero para su escritura, creándolo si no existe. Cursor al final.
- `a+`
  abre un fichero para su escritura y lectura, creándolo si no existe. Cursor al final.

Resumidamente:

| acción | r | r+ | w | w+ | a | a+ |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| leer | + | + |  | + |  | + |
| escribir |  | + | + | + | + | + |
| escribir tras encontrar |  | + | + | + |  |  |
| crear |  |  | + | + | + | + |
| truncar |  |  | + | + | . |  |
| posición al inicio | + | + | + | + |  |  |
| posición al final |  |  |  |  | + | + |

A partir de Python 3 hay otros modos en [`open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/functions.html#open), de modo que en total existen estos:

- `r`
  abrir para lectura (opción por defecto)
- `w`
  abrir para escritura, truncando primero
- `x`
  abrir exclusivamente para crear, de modo que falla si el fichero ya existe
- `a`
  abrir para escribir, añadiendo al final si el fichero ya existe
- `b`
  modo binario
- `t`
  modo texto (opción por defecto)
- `+`
  abrir un fichero de disco para actualizar (leer y escribir)
- `U`
  modo de línea nueva universal (para compatibilidad hacia atrás, no debería usarse en código nuevo)

<sub>Respuesta basada en una mezcla de las respuestas a [Difference between modes a, a+, w, w+, and r+ in built-in open function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1466000/1983854), así como de la documentación oficial de Python.</sub>