# ¿Cómo abrir varios archivos con `with open`?

Tags: python, python-3.x, archivo, operador

Ando buscado cómo hacer entrada/salida de archivos en Python. Escribí el siguiente código para leer una lista de nombres (uno por línea) desde un archivo y escribirlos en otro archivo. Si el nombre leído coincide con un nombre dado por el usuario, le agrego un texto antes de grabarlo. El código funciona, pero ¿cómo podría mejorarlo?

Quiero usar el `with open(...)` para los archivos de entrada y de salida, pero no veo cómo ponerlos en el mismo bloque, lo que significa que tengo que almacenar los nombres momentáneamente en otra parte.

```
def filter(txt, oldfile, newfile):
    '''\
    Lee una lista de nombres desde un archivo línea por línea hacía un archivo de salida.
    Si la línea comienza con un nombre en particular, insertar una cadena de texto
    detrás del nombre antes de añadirlo a la línea del archivo de salida.
    '''

    outfile = open(newfile, 'w')
    with open(oldfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith(txt):
                line = line[0:len(txt)] + ' - Realmente una gran persona!\n'
            outfile.write(line)

    outfile.close()
    return # ¿Gano algo con agregar esto?

# Ingresar los nombres a revisar
text = input('Por favor, ingrese el nombre de una gran persona: ')    
letsgo = filter(text, 'entrada.txt', 'salida.txt')
```

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9282967/how-to-open-a-file-using-the-open-with-statement

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python te permite usar múltiples `open()` dentro de un mismo `with`, sólo tienes que separarlos con comas:

```
with open(newfile, 'w') as outfile, open(oldfile, 'r') as infile:
```

Tú código completo quedará así:

```
def filter(txt, oldfile, newfile):
    '''\
    Lee una lista de nombres desde un archivo línea por línea hacía un archivo de salida.
    Si la línea comienza con un nombre en particular, insertar una cadena de texto
    detrás del nombre antes de añadirlo a la línea del archivo de salida.
    '''

    with open(newfile, 'w') as outfile, open(oldfile, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            if line.startswith(txt):
                line = line[0:len(txt)] + ' - Realmente una gran persona!\n'
            outfile.write(line)

# Ingresar los nombres a revisar
text = input('Por favor, ingrese el nombre de una gran persona: ')    
letsgo = filter(text, 'entrada.txt', 'salida.txt')
```

Es cierto, no ganas nada al poner un `return` explicito al final de la función. Puedes usar un `return` para efectuar una salida anticipada, pero tú lo pusistes al final, y la función retornara igual, aun si no lo pones. (Por supuesto que con funciones que retornan un valor hay que usar `return valor` para especificar dicho valor).

También nos ahorramos el `outfile.close()`, ya que los archivos abiertos con `with open(` se cierran automáticamente al salir del bloque de instrucciones.

En Python 2.5 y 2.6 no se puede usar múltiples `open()` en un `with`, pero desde Python 2.7 y 3.1 en adelante ya se puede.

http://docs.python.org/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement http://docs.python.org/release/3.1/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement